# Google OAuth error Required parameter is missing: grant_type

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth, python-requests

I'm trying this code:

```
import requests
url_token = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
params = {
    'code': request.values.get('code', '', type=str),
    'client_id': app.config['SOCIAL_GOOGLE']['consumer_key'],
    'client_secret': app.config['SOCIAL_GOOGLE']['consumer_secret'],
    'redirect_uri': urllib.quote_plus("https://example.com/google/code"),
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
}
out = requests.post(url_token, params=params)
```

using Python-Request in Flask. But I get error response:

```
ERROR - out={
   "error" : "invalid_request",
   "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

It is standard POST request. Any hint why Google doesn't see grant_type parameter? Or is it misleading error message?

Comment: I'd recommend using the python library that the Google guys developed for the Google API, it will surely help you get rid of a lot of headaches: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

Comment: Thank you for tip. I hoped to solve it with just standard distribution (Ubuntu Linux) libraries (easier updates etc.) and I am already using this (Python-Request) lib on another place in project. For example Facebook OAuth works with no problem.

Comment: OK, it's your decision, however keep in mind that if Google changes it's protocol it would be harder to update your code than to simply update a library.

Comment: That's true. But, for example, now they changed it so much that it is easier to update my code (especially if it is used elsewhere) than to learn and import another single use library (that can be obsolete in future too).
And I understand that it may be different for other users :)

Comment: Yeah, its also a matter of taste, and for little usages of the API its faster to write the requests yourself, however if you later on plan to use Google Drive, Youtube, Analytics, Google+ API's you'll surely reconsider the library approach :)

Comment: Also it's very OK to know the communication details with the API instead of just calling some methods from the libraries. Libraries come into play when dealing with a larger project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is for adding query parameters to the URL in GET requests, `data` is for passing data to POST requests so you should pass the form POST parameters as:

```
out = requests.post(url_token, data=params)
```

see the docs at: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: Oh, I see. I am blind. Thank you.